# Divide rows and then transfer divided values in new worksheet (values: time periods & amounts)

Tags: vba, excel

Hope you can help with this:

In worksheet "TOTALS" and Range "M11:N251" there are "from:to" time periods inserted by user ("From" is in "M11:M" and "To" is in "N11:N"). Number of rows (and inserted time periods) may vary. Time periods are quadrimester (4months) but not always 120 days (could be 119, 122 or sth like that - if less than 100 then user must not be allowed to divide). Range "W11:W251" hosts amounts of money. So, for example, "M11:N11" can be 1/1/13-1/5/13 (dd/mm/yy) and W11 just a number (i.e. 98,45).

I want to be able to divide each time period almost by 2 (first part can be 60 days, second part rest of days) and amounts accordingly (depending on the number of days of its divided period) and transfer the divided periods and amounts to a new worksheet (TOTALS2) to -let's say- range "A11:B251" & "G11:G251").

So, in the above example, in "TOTALS2" we'll have 1/1/13-1/3/13 in "A11:B11" and 1/3/13-1/5/13 in "A12:B12", and the divided amounts accordingly to the counted days of "A11:B11" & "A12:B12" in "G11" and "G12".

And so on until there are no more time periods & amounts in TOTALS to divide and transfer to TOTALS2.

How can this be done? Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

If you want to check out the file, then download it:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/5kudcy

Comment: Ok, either this is too fuzzy to understand or too dumb of a question... Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the file you give in [your link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/5kudcy) where the values in TOTALS start at row 10 (rather than 11 as stated), the prices are in column S (rather than W as stated) and the values in TOTALS2 are to appear in row 10 onwards (rather than row 11 onwards as stated) the following approach works:

Add 5 columns to worksheet TOTALS. These 5 columns have a header in row 9 and formulae in rows 10, 11, 12, etc. Using columns X, Y, Z  and AA the header values in X9:AB9 are

```
Period, Int.To, Int.From, Proportion1, Proportion2
```

(where `Int.` is an abbrevation for intermediate.)

The formulae to use in cells X10 to AB10 are:

X10: `=N10-M10+1`   Calculates number of days from date M10 to date N10, inclusive.

Y10: `=M10+59` Calculates end date of the 60 day period starting on date M10 (i.e calculates last date of first "half period")

Z10: `=1+Y10` Calculates day after date in Y10 (start date of second "half period")

AA10: `=60/X10` Proportion of whole period that is accounted for by first half-period

AB10: `=1-AA10` Proportion of whole period that is accounted for by second half period

The formulae in X10:AB10 can be copied down for as many rows as contain data in worksheet TOTALS, to get something like...

[image: TOTALS worksheet]

The additional columns in TOTALS now provide the information that you need to split each quadrimester into two "halves". Cols M, N, Y and Z provide the date information and S, AA and AB the values for splitting each quadrimester's costs. To get it to display as desired in TOTALS2 you will also need to add a couple of columns to TOTALS2. I've used columns L and M with the following headers in L9 and M9:

```
Source, Part
```

In both L10 and L11 insert the value 1, whilst in M10 and M11 insert the values 1 and 2, respectively. Now add the following formulae to L12 and M12

L12: `=1+L10`

M12: `=M10`

Copy the formulae in L12 and M12 down so that columns L and M contain values in at least twice the number of rows (in TOTALS) that you wish to split into first half and second half periods. You should end up with the sequence `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 etc` in column L and `1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2 etc` in M.

The Source column (L) indicates which data row in TOTALS (1=first, 2=second, 3=third, etc) acts as the source of the values to be split in "half" and the Part column (M) indicates which "half" it is (1=first, 2=second).

All that remains is to put it all together using appropriate formulae in columns A, B and G of TOTALS2. The formulae to insert into A10, B10 and M10 are:

A10: `=OFFSET(IF(M10=1,TOTALS!M$9,TOTALS!Z$9),L10,0)`

B10: `=OFFSET(IF(M10=1,TOTALS!Y$9,TOTALS!N$9),L10,0)`

G10: `=OFFSET(TOTALS!S$9,L10,0)*OFFSET(TOTALS!Z$9,TOTALS2!L10,M10)`

Copy these formulae down the rows in TOTALS2 and it should be looking like...

[image: TOTALS2 Worksheet]

The formulae in col A pick the start dates of the "half" periods using either col M or col Z from the correct Source row in TOTALS, according to whether the Part value is 1 or 2. Similarly, the formulae in col B pick the end dates using cols Y and N of TOTALS. The formulae in G multiply the cost value (col S of TOTALS) by the correct proportion from either col AA or col AB in TOTALS, again according to whether Part is 1 or 2.

I haven't included refinements such as:

- preventing periods which are too short (or long) in TOTALS from being split (hint: you can detect this using the Length column in worksheet TOTALS) or
- controlling the number of displayed rows in TOTALS2 so that it is exactly twice the number of data rows entered in TOTALS (not too difficult and several ways it can be approached) or
- rounding the calculated costs for the two "halves" to 2 decimal places AND making sure that they add back to the original quadrimester cost (it is formatting in the worksheet that is causing only 2 decimals to be displayed and it is not guaranteed that the displayed values will sum precisely to their original source cost - the examples chosen just happen to have this property. Again not too difficult to solve.)

However, the above is a basic solution on which you can build.

Comment: your solution does the trick. thank you very much for your time and effort!